# Open Graph Custom Action Type - built-in action "rate"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

on my website there's the possibility to rate a company. now i implemented oauth and would like to also post this to the rating-user's timeline...

so i created an custom action-type called "review" and an object called "company"... easy going...

the day after i got the answer:

> You’ve submitted a custom review action, which isn’t permitted. Please delete this action type and submit a common rate action instead.
>
> Learn more about actions (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type) and how to implement these actions (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/).

... but looking on these sites i only find **books.rates** and **video.rates**

no "common" rate-action (like og.rate or something)

what am i supposed to do now?